# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, h2

I'm getting this error when trying to insert a charity, because when doing `/admin/charity/new/submit` the charity object is null. I didn't have any problem inserting countries, I'm not an expert in `spring-thymeleaf` but it seems that i'm not trying well the many-to-one relationship.
I'm using Spring Data JPA.

**Model**:

```java
    @Getter @Setter @EqualsAndHashCode @ToString @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    @Table(name = "charities_table")
    public class Charities {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String logo;
        private Double moneyRaised;
        @ManyToOne
        private Country country;
        @Lob 
        private String description;
        public Charities(String name, String description, String logo, Country country, Double moneyRaised) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;
            this.logo = logo;
            this.country = country;
            this.moneyRaised = moneyRaised;
        }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```java
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/admin/charity")
    public class CharitiesController {
        @Autowired
        CharitiesService charitiesService;
        @Autowired
        CountryService countryService;

        @ModelAttribute("charities")
        public List<Charities> charitiesList() {
            return charitiesService.findAll();
        }
        @ModelAttribute("countries")
        public List<Country> countriesList() {
            return countryService.findAll();
        }

        @GetMapping({"/","/list"})
        public String list(Model model) {

            model.addAttribute("charities", charitiesService.findAll());

            return "admin/charity/list";
        }
        @GetMapping("/{id}/delete")
        public String delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Charities charityToDelete = charitiesService.findById(id);
            charitiesService.delete(charityToDelete);
            return "redirect:/admin/charity/list";
        }

        @GetMapping("/new")
        public String newCharityForm(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("charity", new Charities());
            model.addAttribute("countries", countryService.findAll());
            return "admin/charity/form";
        }

        @PostMapping({"/new/submit", "/edit/submit"})
        public String newCharitySubmit(@ModelAttribute Charities charity) {

            charitiesService.insert(charity);
            return "redirect:/admin/charity/list";
        }
        @GetMapping("/{id}/edit")
        public String editCountryForm(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
            Charities charityToEdit = charitiesService.findById(id);
            model.addAttribute("charity", charityToEdit);
            model.addAttribute("countries", countryService.findAll());
            return "admin/charity/edit";
        }
    }
```

**And here is the view**:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
      <form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/admin/charity/new/submit}" th:object="${charity}">
        <h1>New Charity</h1>
        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" th:field="*{id}" />
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" th:field="*{name}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="logo">Logo</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="logo" placeholder="Logo" th:field="*{logo}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="moneyRaised">Money Raised</label> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="moneyRaised" placeholder="Money Raised" th:field="*{moneyRaised}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="country">Country</label>
          <select th:field="*{country}" id="country" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="country: ${countries}" th:value="${country.id}" th:text="${country.name}"></option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label> <textarea class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Description" th:field="*{description}"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      </form>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Error:**

```
    Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Target object must not be null; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.raiseItUp.demo.RaiseItUp.service.CharitiesService.insert(CharitiesService.java:16)
        at com.raiseItUp.demo.RaiseItUp.controller.CharitiesController.newCharitySubmit(CharitiesController.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:64)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target object must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setWrappedInstance(BeanWrapperImpl.java:153)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setWrappedInstance(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:183)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.<init>(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.<init>(BeanWrapperImpl.java:103)
        at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.<init>(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:36)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.getId(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractEntityInformation.isNew(AbstractEntityInformation.java:42)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.isNew(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:237)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:553)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 99 more
```

Comment: How does your ```charitiesService.insert(charity);``` method look like? Please share the full error-message. On which line does the error occure?

Comment: I updated my post with the full-error message

Comment: @TomStroemer it looks like this: `public Charities insert(Charities c) { return repository.save(c); ` and the repository is extending a JPA Repository. The error occures at line 60 when inserting the charity.

Comment: @Pierre Were you able to resolve the error? I'm having the same issue, and the error message is pointing to an irrelevant line in my Thymeleaf template. Moreover, I carefully checked that I'm properly setting the model attributes in the controller so not sure exactly why the target object is null. Any idea?